# How to deal with multiple date format? Spark - Scala

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark-sql, date-format

I have data in `Json` format like this

```
....
{"Title":"51 Birch Street","US_Gross":84689,"Worldwide_Gross":84689,"US_DVD_Sales":null,"Production_Budget":350000,"Release_Date":"18-Oct-06","MPAA_Rating":"Not Rated","Running_Time_min":null,"Distributor":"Truly Indie","Source":null,"Major_Genre":null,"Creative_Type":null,"Director":null,"Rotten_Tomatoes_Rating":97,"IMDB_Rating":7.4,"IMDB_Votes":439}
{"Title":"55 Days at Peking","US_Gross":10000000,"Worldwide_Gross":10000000,"US_DVD_Sales":null,"Production_Budget":17000000,"Release_Date":"1963-01-01","MPAA_Rating":null,"Running_Time_min":null,"Distributor":null,"Source":"Original Screenplay","Major_Genre":"Drama","Creative_Type":null,"Director":null,"Rotten_Tomatoes_Rating":57,"IMDB_Rating":6.8,"IMDB_Votes":2104}
{"Title":"Nine 1/2 Weeks","US_Gross":6734844,"Worldwide_Gross":6734844,"US_DVD_Sales":null,"Production_Budget":18000000,"Release_Date":"21-Feb-86","MPAA_Rating":null,"Running_Time_min":null,"Distributor":"MGM","Source":"Based on Book/Short Story","Major_Genre":"Drama","Creative_Type":"Contemporary Fiction","Director":"Adrian Lyne","Rotten_Tomatoes_Rating":null,"IMDB_Rating":5.4,"IMDB_Votes":12731}
{"Title":"AstÈrix aux Jeux Olympiques","US_Gross":999811,"Worldwide_Gross":132999811,"US_DVD_Sales":null,"Production_Budget":113500000,"Release_Date":"4-Jul-08","MPAA_Rating":"Not Rated","Running_Time_min":null,"Distributor":"Alliance","Source":"Based on Comic/Graphic Novel","Major_Genre":"Adventure","Creative_Type":"Fantasy","Director":null,"Rotten_Tomatoes_Rating":null,"IMDB_Rating":4.9,"IMDB_Votes":5620}
{"Title":"The Abyss","US_Gross":54243125,"Worldwide_Gross":54243125,"US_DVD_Sales":null,"Production_Budget":70000000,"Release_Date":"9-Aug-89","MPAA_Rating":"PG-13","Running_Time_min":null,"Distributor":"20th Century Fox","Source":"Original Screenplay","Major_Genre":"Action","Creative_Type":"Science Fiction","Director":"James Cameron","Rotten_Tomatoes_Rating":88,"IMDB_Rating":7.6,"IMDB_Votes":51018}
{"Title":"Action Jackson","US_Gross":20257000,"Worldwide_Gross":20257000,"US_DVD_Sales":null,"Production_Budget":7000000,"Release_Date":"12-Feb-88","MPAA_Rating":null,"Running_Time_min":null,"Distributor":"Lorimar Motion Pictures","Source":"Original Screenplay","Major_Genre":"Action","Creative_Type":"Contemporary Fiction","Director":null,"Rotten_Tomatoes_Rating":10,"IMDB_Rating":4.6,"IMDB_Votes":3856}
{"Title":"Ace Ventura: Pet Detective","US_Gross":72217396,"Worldwide_Gross":107217396,"US_DVD_Sales":null,"Production_Budget":12000000,"Release_Date":"4-Feb-94","MPAA_Rating":"PG-13","Running_Time_min":null,"Distributor":"Warner Bros.","Source":"Original Screenplay","Major_Genre":"Comedy","Creative_Type":"Contemporary Fiction","Director":"Tom Shadyac","Rotten_Tomatoes_Rating":49,"IMDB_Rating":6.6,"IMDB_Votes":63543}
{"Title":"Ace Ventura: When Nature Calls","US_Gross":108360063,"Worldwide_Gross":212400000,"US_DVD_Sales":null,"Production_Budget":30000000,"Release_Date":"10-Nov-95","MPAA_Rating":"PG-13","Running_Time_min":null,"Distributor":"Warner Bros.","Source":"Original Screenplay","Major_Genre":"Comedy","Creative_Type":"Contemporary Fiction","Director":"Steve Oedekerk","Rotten_Tomatoes_Rating":null,"IMDB_Rating":5.6,"IMDB_Votes":51275}
{"Title":"April Fool's Day","US_Gross":12947763,"Worldwide_Gross":12947763,"US_DVD_Sales":null,"Production_Budget":5000000,"Release_Date":"27-Mar-86","MPAA_Rating":null,"Running_Time_min":null,"Distributor":"Paramount Pictures","Source":"Original Screenplay","Major_Genre":"Horror","Creative_Type":"Contemporary Fiction","Director":null,"Rotten_Tomatoes_Rating":31,"IMDB_Rating":null,"IMDB_Votes":null}
{"Title":"Among Giants","US_Gross":64359,"Worldwide_Gross":64359,"US_DVD_Sales":null,"Production_Budget":4000000,"Release_Date":"26-Mar-99","MPAA_Rating":"R","Running_Time_min":null,"Distributor":"Fox Searchlight","Source":"Original Screenplay","Major_Genre":"Romantic Comedy","Creative_Type":null,"Director":null,"Rotten_Tomatoes_Rating":null,"IMDB_Rating":5.7,"IMDB_Votes":546}
{"Title":"Annie Get Your Gun","US_Gross":8000000,"Worldwide_Gross":8000000,"US_DVD_Sales":null,"Production_Budget":3768785,"Release_Date":"17-May-50","MPAA_Rating":null,"Running_Time_min":null,"Distributor":"MGM","Source":"Based on Book/Short Story","Major_Genre":"Musical","Creative_Type":null,"Director":null,"Rotten_Tomatoes_Rating":100,"IMDB_Rating":7.1,"IMDB_Votes":1326}
{"Title":"Alice in Wonderland","US_Gross":0,"Worldwide_Gross":0,"US_DVD_Sales":null,"Production_Budget":3000000,"Release_Date":"28-Jul-51","MPAA_Rating":null,"Running_Time_min":null,"Distributor":"RKO Radio Pictures","Source":"Based on Book/Short Story","Major_Genre":"Musical","Creative_Type":null,"Director":null,"Rotten_Tomatoes_Rating":20,"IMDB_Rating":6.7,"IMDB_Votes":63458}
{"Title":"The Princess and the Cobbler","US_Gross":669276,"Worldwide_Gross":669276,"US_DVD_Sales":null,"Production_Budget":24000000,"Release_Date":"25-Aug-95","MPAA_Rating":"G","Running_Time_min":null,"Distributor":"Miramax","Source":"Original Screenplay","Major_Genre":"Adventure","Creative_Type":"Fantasy","Director":null,"Rotten_Tomatoes_Rating":null,"IMDB_Rating":7.3,"IMDB_Votes":893}
....
```

where I have several date formats in the field `"Release_Date"` like `26-Mar-99` or `1963-01-01` or `4-Jul-08`

I have some code working

```scala
      val moviesDF = spark.read
        .option("inferSchema", "true")
        .json(s"${path}/movies.json")

       moviesDF.show(truncate = false)

      val moviesWithReleaseDates = moviesDF
        .select(col("Title"), to_date(col("Release_Date"), "dd-MMM-yy").as("Actual_Release")) // conversion
      moviesWithReleaseDates.show(truncate = false)
```

but the output

```
|Four Rooms                                |1995-12-25    |
|The Four Seasons                          |1981-05-22    |
|Four Weddings and a Funeral               |1994-03-09    |
|51 Birch Street                           |2006-10-18    |
|55 Days at Peking                         |null          |
|Nine 1/2 Weeks                            |1986-02-21    |
|AstÈrix aux Jeux Olympiques               |2008-07-04    |
|The Abyss                                 |1989-08-09    |
|Action Jackson                            |1988-02-12    |
|Ace Ventura: Pet Detective                |1994-02-04    |
```

when the date format is like `"18-Oct-06"` it is working fine, but when the date format is different it is showing nulls.

To show all the dates without nulls, how could I do this in a simple and elegant way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

It's because `to_date(col("Release_Date"), "dd-MMM-yy")`. Here you are providing input date format & it reads correctly if json date format matches this . If not, it would null

Now you have to read date text from json with all possible date formats.

Write a udf. Pass date text as input to it. In udf, check for possible date format & if matches, return proper date object. UDF is certainly helpful here

Answer (score 3):

In any case you need to have the finite list of date format you have in the file for `Release_Date` or you want to support in the processing.

you can write `udf` to parse the `date string` using below method -

```scala
val formatStrings = Seq("dd-MMM-yy", "yyyy-MM-dd","other-formats")
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
    def tryParse(dateString: String): java.util.Date = {
      val parser: String => java.util.Date = dateStr => new SimpleDateFormat(dateStr).parse(dateString)
      formatStrings.map(parser).filter(_ != null).head
    }
```

or use `coalesce`

```scala
coalesce(
to_date(col("Release_Date"), "dd-MMM-yy"),
to_date(col("Release_Date"), "yyyy-MM-dd"),
to_date(col("Release_Date"), "other-date-format")
).as("Actual_Release")
```

or

```scala
val dt_formats= Seq("dd-MMM-yyyy", "MMM-dd-yyyy", "yyyy-MM-dd","MM/dd/yy","dd-MM-yy","dd-MM-yyyy","yyyy/MM/dd","dd/MM/yyyy")

val newDF =  df.withColumn("Actual_Release", coalesce(dt_formats.map(fmt => to_date($"Release_Date", fmt)):_*))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this, I don't know if it is elegant but simple it is:

```scala
val mWRD = moviesDF.selectExpr("""Title""",
"""IF(LENGTH(Release_Date) <= 9,to_date(Release_Date,'dd-MMM-yy'),
to_date(Release_Date,'yyyy-MM-dd')) AS Actual_Release""")
mWRD.show(truncate = false)
```